# Linking Auth0 and Parse Server users

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, auth0

I am writing an app that uses Parse Server, with Auth0 as the authentication provider. For unrelated reasons, we need to use Auth0 rather than Parse for user management.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to "link" a user authenticated via Auth0 to Objects in Parse Server. Without this, the authenticated user will not have permission to write to his/her Objects on the Parse Server. I believe my issue is similar to this question, which has no solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069817/custom-authentication-integration-with-parse-server-and-auth0%20here).

I have found many articles discussing the migration of users from Parse to Auth0, but am finding surprisingly little documentation on how to link those users to Parse. There is [one article](https://medium.com/adrian-brink/parse-server-auth0-integration-e10de20e663f#.c7pqgokd7) (I believe written by the same person who posted the question I linked to), but I couldn't get it to work,  and it involves storing passwords in cleartext in Javascript.

I thought to create a default Parse user that would simply own all the objects in Parse. This would be invisible to the authenticated end-user so they wouldn't know, but that's just security by obscurity and doesn't seem like a good approach.

If anyone has suggestions on how to approach this, or has done it before, I'm interested to read your suggestions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 supports the most common and used authentication protocols (OAuth2/OIDC, SAML and WS-Federation) so configuring an application to rely on Auth0 is really easy when that application already talks one of the previously mentioned protocols.

According to the Parse Server Wiki, it does [support custom authentication leveraging OAuth](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/OAuth--and-Custom-Authentication) so that seems your best starting point for integrating Auth0 with a Parse Server based application.

> It is possible to leverage the OAuth support with any 3rd party authentication that you bring in.

---

**Disclaimer:** I never used the Parse service or Parse Server so I'm assuming that when you mean linking Parse objects to users this can be accomplished by simply having an authenticated user in Parse and the identity of that user is just verified and proven by Auth0 instead of something like built-in username/passwords managed by Parse itself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm aware that Auth0 CAN work with Parse Server.. I just cannot figure out where to even begin to make that happen. What few docs I've found have either been out-dated or do not apply.

Comment: Hey @mrbranden, where you able to find resources for this task?