# How to keep client secret for OAuth2 login to Parse server secure?

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, oauth-2.0, parse-server

I want to enable users in my macos app to be able to securely login to my [Parse Server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) using third-party Oauth2 login. I have been searching for the best approach to do this, but still have some problems. If I understand correctly, logging in requires:

1. Enable oauth in my Parse server config file (for twitter, google etc).
2. Get the access token to the provider (e.g. twitter) using a client side OAuth login. I am currently using [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift).
3. Login to Parse using the provided access token (from 2) as suggested in the [swift example provided here](https://gist.github.com/flovilmart/68a6c538496953408bb1), i.e.

   ```
   [[PFUser logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:provider authData:authData] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask<id> *task) {
    return task;
   }];
   ```

This login approach requires the use of the **client key** and **client secret** for each provider. How can I safely store these keys-secrets on my Parse server and access them programmatically? Should I use [PFConfig](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFConfig.html) and access them during runtime? Is that safe? Or is there something I am doing very wrong here? If anyone has a better approach or an example as to how I should enable OAuth login I would appreciate it (since I am on macos I can not use TwitterUtils and FacebookUtils).

Answer (score 1):

No secret key should ever be used on your client.  The client key can be considered "public", and is actually optional (though recommended).

Your secret key should *only* be stored on your server, preferably as a config/env variable (Note: NOT PFCONFIG).  Any use of it should be on your server, and you can create a cloud code function that will use the key as needed and return necessary values to your client. The client should call this, receive a key you need, and then use it appropriately.

Although I'm also not familiar with a client secret key in general? This is the first I've seen of it. I wonder if you've misunderstood any documentation?