# Parse on AWS 503 error when calling from Auth0 and ok from local

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I am trying to implement Auth0 integration described [here](https://medium.com/adrian-brink/parse-server-auth0-integration-e10de20e663f#.ombu5efnz). Login attempt returns 404 which is fine.

However on POST I get
54.67.15.170 - - [28/Nov/2016:14:26:54 +0000] "GET /parse/login?username=auth0%7C0123456789&password=XXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 404 49
54.67.15.170 - - [28/Nov/2016:14:26:55 +0000] "POST /parse/users/ HTTP/1.1" 503 299

Creating user from local:
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appid" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:mk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"Sean Plott","password":"aaaaaaa"}' https://tablebuds.com/parse/users
{"objectId":"2H32s7C45c","createdAt":"2016-11-28T14:29:50.515Z","sessionToken":"r:XXXXX"}
works fine.

Can anyone suggest what I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are the parameters of your POST?  Here is what the documentation says they should be:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username":"cooldude6","password":"p_n7!-e8","phone":"415-392-0202"}' \
  https://YOURAWS/parse/users
```

I think the X-Parse-REST-API-Key is optional on parse-server though.

Comment: Here is exact call which is done from Auth0:
    Sorry can't get code formatted correctly
    request.post({
  url: SERVER_NAME + '/parse/users',
  json: {
  username: username,
  password: PARSE_USER_PASSWORD,
  email: email,
  emailVerified: true
 },
 headers: {
  'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_APP_ID,
  'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_API_KEY,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
 }
    </code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way call is being made. Removing initial request.get which fails eliminates the problem which on the server seems to be around ParseServer.js:395
         process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
          if (err.code === "EADDRINUSE") {

```
 request.get({
 url: SERVER_NAME + '/parse/login',
 qs: {
     username: username,
     password: PARSE_USER_PASSWORD
     },
     headers: {
       'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_APP_ID,
       'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_API_KEY
     } 
}, function (err, response, body) {

if (err) return callback(err);
// user was found, add sessionToken to user profile
if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    user.parse_session_token = JSON.parse(body).sessionToken;
    return callback(null, user, context);
} // Not found. Likely the user doesn’t exist, we provision one
if(response.statusCode === 404) {
   request.post({
   url: SERVER_NAME + '/parse/users',
   json: {
   username: username,
   password: PARSE_USER_PASSWORD,
   email: email,
   emailVerified: true
},
headers: {
 'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_APP_ID,
 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_API_KEY,
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
}, function (err, response, body) {
 if (err) return callback(err);
    // user created, add sessionToken to user profile
    if (response.statusCode === 201) {
    user.parse_session_token = body.sessionToken;
 return callback(null, user, context);
}
  return callback(new Error("The user provisioning returned a)));
});
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that apache error log has
[Sat Dec 03 02:10:18.478045 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 1149] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:1337 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Dec 03 02:10:18.478083 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1149] [client 54.67.15.170:57606] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1

this seems like an Auth0 client. AWS 1337 ports are open for Auth0 IPs though.

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT! permission on log file creation were throwing exception that was causing server to shut down and miss the second call. Thank you.